# FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, watson

I'm trying to follow the steps from the readme of   [1]: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk but, Getting the following error:

```
FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper (System.IFormatProvider provider, System.String format, System.ParamsArray args) (at <c95265f74fdf4905bfb0d5a4b652216c>:0)
System.String.FormatHelper (System.IFormatProvider provider, System.String format, System.ParamsArray args) (at <c95265f74fdf4905bfb0d5a4b652216c>:0)
System.String.Format (System.String format, System.Object[] args) (at <c95265f74fdf4905bfb0d5a4b652216c>:0)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging.LogRecord..ctor (IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging.LogLevel level, System.String subSystem, System.String messageFmt, System.Object[] args) (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Scripts/Logging/Logger.cs:91)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging.Log.Debug (System.String subSystem, System.String messageFmt, System.Object[] args) (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Scripts/Logging/Logger.cs:216)
ExampleStreaming+<RecordingHandler>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Examples/ServiceExamples/Scripts/ExampleStreaming.cs:112)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Utilities.Runnable+Routine.MoveNext () (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Scripts/Utilities/Runnable.cs:128)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Utilities.Routine:.ctor(IEnumerator) (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Scripts/Utilities/Runnable.cs:114)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Utilities.Runnable:Run(IEnumerator) (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Scripts/Utilities/Runnable.cs:47)
ExampleStreaming:StartRecording() (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Examples/ServiceExamples/Scripts/ExampleStreaming.cs:89)
ExampleStreaming:Start() (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Examples/ServiceExamples/Scripts/ExampleStreaming.cs:53)
```

and

```
[02-15-2018 19:17:07][Unity][CRITICAL] 
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Debug.DebugReactor:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Scripts/Debug/DebugReactor.cs:60)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging.LogSystem:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Scripts/Logging/Logger.cs:196)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging.Log:Critical(String, String, Object[]) (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Scripts/Logging/Logger.cs:274)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging.LogSystem:UnityLogCallback(String, String, LogType) (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Scripts/Logging/Logger.cs:157)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Utilities.Routine:.ctor(IEnumerator) (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Scripts/Utilities/Runnable.cs:114)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Utilities.Runnable:Run(IEnumerator) (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Scripts/Utilities/Runnable.cs:47)
ExampleStreaming:StartRecording() (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Examples/ServiceExamples/Scripts/ExampleStreaming.cs:89)
ExampleStreaming:Start() (at Assets/Watson-sdk/Examples/ServiceExamples/Scripts/ExampleStreaming.cs:53)
```

BTW I'm getting these 2 log messages too :

```
[02-21-2018 17:34:39][SpeechToText.CreateListenConnector()][DEBUG] Created listen socket. Model: en-US_BroadbandModel, parsedParams: 
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Debug.DebugReactor:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at Assets/Watson/Scripts/Debug/DebugReactor.cs:68)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging.LogSystem:ProcessLog(LogRecord) (at Assets/Watson/Scripts/Logging/Logger.cs:196)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging.Log:Debug(String, String, Object[]) (at Assets/Watson/Scripts/Logging/Logger.cs:216)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Services.SpeechToText.v1.SpeechToText:CreateListenConnector() (at Assets/Watson/Scripts/Services/SpeechToText/v1/SpeechToText.cs:635)
IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Services.SpeechToText.v1.SpeechToText:StartListening(OnRecognize, OnRecognizeSpeaker) (at Assets/Watson/Scripts/Services/SpeechToText/v1/SpeechToText.cs:494)
ExampleStreaming:set_Active(Boolean) (at Assets/Watson/Examples/ServiceExamples/Scripts/ExampleStreaming.cs:82)
ExampleStreaming:Start() (at Assets/Watson/Examples/ServiceExamples/Scripts/ExampleStreaming.cs:58)
```

and

```
There are 0 candidate types
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
FullSerializer.PlayStateNotifier:ModeChanged(PlayModeStateChange) (at Assets/Watson/ThirdParty/FullSerializer/Aot/Editor/fsAotConfigurationEditor.cs:28)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: The index you use to access an array should be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the array. And that's the best help you're going to get from Stack Overflow because you didn't post your code.

Comment: Well, I did understand the array should be <= 0 and less than length but, the code is in the github repo : https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk File name:Assets/Watson-sdk/Examples/ServiceExamples/Scripts/ExampleStreaming.cs

Comment: Its their example code that's a problem? Why in God's name are you asking **us**? Go to ***them*** and report a problem.

Comment: Can you try with a different microphone?

Comment: @taj, I'm using my laptop inbuilt mic. I tried with my headphones too. But not working

Comment: It looks like the microphone is not working. Can you ensure you are able to get audio using your microphone/headphones? Also please post your ExampleStreaming.cs code

Comment: @taj. Thanks. Yes the audio drivers were the culprit. I reinstalled the audio drivers for the microphone and the program works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the audio source. It looks like no audio is coming in.